# Why does asyncio.sleep() seem to suspend coroutine created using create_task()?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following code that is interpreted using python 3.8:

```
import asyncio

async def stuff(name,time):
    print("starting ",name)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    #UNREACHABLE CODE
    print("finished ",name)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print("start")
    t1 = loop.create_task(stuff("A",1))
    t2 = loop.create_task(stuff("B",1))
    print("end")
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I expect the output to be:

```
start
end
starting A
starting B
finished A
finsihed B
```

However,
I get:

```
start
end
starting  A
starting  B
```

Where `print("finished ",name)` seems to be unreachable code

Comment: Nothing is awaiting the completion of those tasks. Only the completion of `main` is awaited, and that ends before the tasks it spawned.

Comment: I just added `await t1` and `await t2` and it works as expected. However, the tasks are already spawned as `starting A` and `starting B` are printed.

Comment: Yes, but then the loop ends while those tasks are sleeping, because nobody told the loop to wait for the tasks to complete.